# Statically served vue-router app by Flask shows 404 for custom pages on Heroku

Tags: vue.js, flask, heroku, vue-router

I've gone through several Stack Overflow pages and [the official Vue guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#heroku), but my app still returns 404 results when going to a different page.

The structure of my app looks like this, with a `client` folder that has the Vue app and a `server` folder containing `app.py` that statically serves the `index.html` in the `client/dist` folder through Flask.

[image]

Contents of `static.json` are as outlined in the guide:

```js
{
  "root": "client/dist",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

with just modified `root` folder to go to `client/dist`. Running the app locally with `npm run serve` works, as does opening it up on its Heroku page and clicking on the nav. However, directly going to a page, such as `/translate`, always returns 404.

I have installed the following buildpacks:

```
=== readiglot Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/python
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static
```

The app is hosted here: https://www.readiglot.herokuapp.com.

On `npm run build` from the root directory, the `dist` folder is built by Heroku in the `client` folder.

Am I missing something? Could anyone advise as to additional configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the `app.py` file - you need to statically serve the file using a catch all route.

```py
@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<string:path>")
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

By putting the `serve_static_file` in the Flask app to redirect from all other routes, 404 only shows up on a true 404.